# Cropping an image diagonally with CSS and adding a border

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to achieve an effect where I can diagonally crop an image in a way that is displayed below. I am aware of clip path as a solution but it would not be suitable in this scenario since it is not supported by certain browsers which are essential for this particular task. (IE and Edge)

Additionally, the cropped edge would need a black border which adds on to the complexity of what I am trying to do. Having searched for answers and coming up with anything, any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could overlay the image with a rotated element (div or something) that you give a border and white background. This solution would work if you're okay with a solid background color.

Another solution, depending on your requirements, could be to simpy use a .png image with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, it's a bit tricky to get the sizes of the divs correct. But here's generally how to do it:

HTML:

```
<div id="outerwrapper">
    <div id="innerwrapper">
        <div id="content">
            <span>asdf</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}

#content span {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}

#innerwrapper {
    border-right: solid 3px black;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#outerwrapper {
    transform: rotate(60deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ywfpeve8/

To explain this:
You have a div that contains the content itself. In this example it's just a span, but it can be anything. (I put it in to see that in the end everything is horizontal again)
You rotate that content div to some degree that suits you.

You place that div in a wrapper with a different size where you can position your content in. That div has an `overflow: hidden`, to crop all that content that is outside of the inner wrapper box. That wrapper then also has the border where you want the crop to be highlighted.

That inner wrapper is placed in an outside wrapper that rotates the same amount at the content div, but *backwards*, leaving you with the original 0 degree alignment of the content. This div again has `overflow: hidden` to crop that inner wrapper *again* so that you can hide the other "crop edges" that you want to be invisible. In my example code I didn't to the correct dimensions and positionings as it takes a bit to get right. But if you have an image with a white background, that shouldn't be very hard anymore to get things right.

Bonus: the background of the top-level element (that element that holds the `outerwrapper` can have any background at all and you won't see a rectangular box at the bottom right corner (for this example) as everything just happens with `overflow: hidden` and without bars that go over the content to hide it :)